# I need to display properly my form.text_area with Simple_format

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to display properly my form.text_area with CR (carriage return when the enter key is press(in display show)

I have tried to use simple_format `(<%= form.text_area :description %>)` but it's not work.

```rb
<!-- Description -->
<div class="field">
  <label>Description : </label>
  <div class="<%=ticket.errors[:description].empty? ? 'field' : 'field error'%>">
    simple_format(<%= form.text_area :description %>)
  /div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't appear to be a valid `ERB` expression. You need something like:

`<%= form.text_area(:description, value: simple_format(:description)) %>`

Here's a link to more documentation on the `text_area` method: https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/text_area

Comment: Ok thanks for the tips. Actually, that does not work but I will investigate that